# Linear algebra: matrix column vector linear dependence inferred from F2 row vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, information-theory

[Parity check matrix determines minimal distance of a linear code.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2716082/parity-check-matrix-determines-minimal-distance-of-a-linear-code)

"Then, because c0Ht=0, this implies that d columns of H (those corresponding to the non-zero elements of c0) are LD (linearly dependent)"

I'm failing to see how it works... In F2 (each element is either 0 or 1), why does a 1xn vector multiplying an nxm matrix = 0 implies that the column vectors of the mxn matrix is linearly dependent at indices where the the elements of the 1xn vector = 1? Thank you so much for your time and help...

Comment: If a matrix $A$ has a non-trivial nullspace it has linearly dependent columns. So for any non-zero vector $v$ if $Av=0$ it has linearly dependent columns.

Comment: @CyclotomicField thanks... but how do the indices of such columns in M = indices of value 1 in the 1xn vector? ;-;

Comment: Try some small examples to see what's happening. It's because the only non-trivial element of $F_2$ is $1$.